# Split output text in ionic barcode scanner

Tags: javascript, android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have implemented the barcode/QR scanner using ionic/cordova. I am able to successfully display the text on the screen. But the issue i am facing is that i am not able to split the text i am displaying on the screen.
example: in the qr code is have data like
"a,b,c,d". So using qr scanner i am able to display a,b,c,d in a single field. But the requirement is to populate different field on output screen by splitting the value based on ",". Below is the code:

```html
<html>
<ion-content>
<button ion-button round color="primary" (click)="analyze();">Analyze</button>
<div *ngIf="results">

<p ng-model="names"> 
{{results.text}}
</p>
<p id="input1"></p>
<p id="input2"></p>
<p id="input3"></p>
<p id="input4"></p>
</div>
<ion-content>
</html>
In the .ts file
<script>
async analyze()
{

this.results = await this.barcode.scan();

var str = this.results; //(var str = how,are,you) is working

var res = new Array();

res = str.split(;);

document.getElementById(input1).innerHTML = res[0];

document.getElementById(input2).innerHTML = res[1];

document.getElementById(input3).innerHTML = res[2];

document.getElementById(input4).innerHTML = res[3];

}
</script>
```

Now we need to split the data and display each splited data in different field. I am modifying the above script and trying but it is not working.

---

Split function is working fine as if i put var str = how,are,you instead of var str = this.results; , i am getting the outpu. But how do is capture the scanned value and split?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
UES

Comment: You have to show us how `this.barcode.scan();` is implemented

Comment: You need to console out the output of `this.results` and paste it here.